# Как узнать chat id для отправки сообщения в чат telegram?

Tags: node.js, telegraf

При работе с telegraf.js как можно узнать id чата для отправки сообщения при добавлении бота в групу?

```
  const Telegraf = require('telegraf')
const config = require ('./config.json')


const bot = new Telegraf(config.token)

bot.start((ctx) => ctx.reply('Welcome'))
bot.help((ctx) => ctx.reply('Send me a sticker'))
bot.on('new_chat_members', (ctx) => console.log(ctx.message.new_chat_members))
bot.hears('hi', (ctx) => ctx.reply('Hey there'))
bot.hears(/buy/i, (ctx) => ctx.reply('Buy-buy'))


bot.telegram.sendMessage(chat.id,'sd')


bot.startPolling()
```

Answer (score 1):

Легко, Вам необходимо просто вытащить с объекта ctx. Получится вот так:

```
ctx.message.chat.id
```